# Windows 7 64 Chrome 19 font anti-aliasing render issue

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, antialiasing

I just loaded a new system and everything looked fine. Then all of the sudden Chrome starting displaying certain fonts on certain web pages with what looks like no anti-aliasing. I've had this happen before on another system as well. Same thing, everything looked fine and then all of the sudden this started. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Screenshot of what I'm typically seeing.

http://www.denkers.com/test/font.jpg

Comment: At least to me, it sounds a lot more like a problem with configuration than code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your text encoding is correctly set to Unicode (UTF-8) by going to the wrench icon -> Tools -> Encoding
If that doesn't work, go to the wrench -> About Google Chrome and update to the latest version.
Finally, if none of these work, try reinstalling Google Chrome.